# Ionic2: Send params between pages (When clicking on the return nav button) using navParam

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

Does anyone know how returns a simple value (or `JSON`) by clicking on the `nav` return button on ionic2?
I know that `navParam` is able to send a value on `push`, but I didn't find anything about the `pop` action and connect the return `nav` button to my new pop action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [open feature request](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5724) about back navigation with parameters.

One solution is to pass a Promise through NavParams:

*Parent*

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.nav.push(ChildPage, {resolve: resolve});
}).then(data => {
  // process data
});
```

*Child*

```
this.navParams.get('resolve')('some data');
```

Comment: Hi, it seem that the opts are only for transition :p

Comment: Can you just add to use the ngOnDestroy to call in child to answerd 100% my question for the next people. THanks you again

Comment: Thank you very much. This works fine, it allows me to pass parameters back on pop just like I wanted.